# Will `quicksort 3way` be slower than `quicksort` in general case?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

[Qucksort 3way](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort-3-way) aims to help the case where many/most items in the array are equal.

**My question is that will `quicksort 3way` beats `quicksort` in general case?**

by general case, I mean not many items are equal or further, all items are distinct.

I have done some benchmarks and my feeling is that in general case, `quicksort 3way` is even worse than the classic `quicksort`.

Comment: This can be answered with a more precise definition of "general case". Why not try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a little thought: you have an algorithm designed to help you solve a worse case scenario for another algorithm. Of course it is not supposed to beat the initial algorithm in the general case. Idea in 3 way quicksort is to improve worst case behavior not the average case one.

Comment: I think your answer is quite too high level, right? I am here actually acting why, instead of the high level logic reason

Comment: You have not provided any details about your particular implementations. I can not give a much more detailed answer this way. Please note this sentence from your link: `The 3-way partitioning code shown above is written for clarity rather than optimal performance; it exhibits poor locality, and performs more swaps than necessary.`